# Scaling the application and Handling WM_DPICHANGED message

Tags: delphi, scaling, dpi

I am trying to make my Delphi 10.3 application dpi aware and I understand that I must handle the `WM_DPICHANGED` message for that. I encountered 2 problems:

1. I don't receive `WM_DPICHANGED` message at all, although I have included the "Per Monitor V2" setting in the manifest file. I don't have multiple monitors so I can only test by changing the OS scaling setting. Or this is not supossed to trigger that message ? If not, then why the Notepad windows it is scaled accordingly (see the video) ? How can I make my app to react in the same way ?
2. How can I do the scaling when I receive the `WM_DPICHANGED` ? Normally, I would have called some of the scaling functions, like `ScaleBy()`, but [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged) that I must use `SetWindowPos` with the value provided in LPARAM, if not, I will trigger some infinite loop. But this will only scale my window size, and I want to scale all window content.

*Secondary question: Is there a way to trigger that message, other than having 2 monitors ?*

Video demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6DF3MZUD7w

Test app, just to see if I receive the message... but no "x" appears in the caption:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    CheckBox2: TCheckBox;
    CheckBox3: TCheckBox;
    procedure DpiChanged(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_DPICHANGED;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.DpiChanged(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
 caption:= caption + ' x';
 //ScaleBy(Screen.PixelsPerInch + UserPPI, LastPPI);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Delphi 10.3 already implements WM_DPICHANGED in TCustomForm class, so you don't have to do anything in that regard.

Comment: Testing without two monitors will work flaky.

Comment: I do not use the Delphi default scaling. I set all `TForm.Scaled` to `False` and scaling manually, because I want to have a custom scaling, like a compensation, above all other scaling parameters.

Comment: Ok, I saw in Delphi source how `WM_DPICHANGED` is handled... But if I can't trigger that without 2 monitors, to test how it works, I think I will leave my app only with System DPI awareness... But at least I want to make it scale when windows scale factor changes (like Notepad in my question video). What should I hook to get notified when that happens ?

Comment: I found that `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` is fireed when windows scaling is changed, but now, the problem is that I have nowhere to get the new value of the PPI, because is not updated anywhere. I tried `Screen.PixelPerInch`, API call `GetDpiForSystem`... They all still have the old value... :(

Comment: What DPI awareness setting do you have in Project Options->Application->Manifest? By Default Delphi 10.3 sets this to `Per Monitor v2`. So perhaps you will need to change this to `System Aware`.